# How to modify magento product template?

Tags: magento, php

I would like to change the product page template in our magento store. Can you please advice how to insert this tag "/PACK" beside the product price?

See image links: http://www.thebodyshop.ie/price-pack/?___store=default
The second one, at the bottom would be the goal.

Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the `price.phtml` file from `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product`
And paste it into your `theme_package_folder/template/catalog/product`.
Approx 201 and 203 lines you can find code to display price and final price in frontend.

```
<?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_price, true, true) ?>
<?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_finalPrice, true, true) ?>
```

replace it with

```
<?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_price, true, true).'/PACK' ?>
<?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_finalPrice, true, true).'/PACK' ?>
```

If you want you can even give span to `'/pack'` and give your css.

Comment: Hi Shivanand, Thank you for the excellence advice. All working perfect now, thanks a lot for your professional skills.